# Can I turn on a camera remotely using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, camera, tracking, detection, identification

I'm on a project and I have two cameras. The first camera makes a detection and tracking of people while the second is to make a person identification.
I want to turn on the second camera when I detect a person. I want to know if we can turn on a camera (like Axis) remotely using Matlab?

Comment: Depends on your camera - http://uk.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/usbwebcams/ug/acquire-images-from-webcams.html